# ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework: Need help on next steps to take

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am a newbie to MVC and I am trying to build a basic web application that will simulate some of the features of online banking. So far, I have been able to set up User accounts and link that with SimpleMembership as well as implement some simple CRUD functionality for account management.

**EDIT:**

I want the transfer to work something like this below and have the user select account1 and account2 from a dropdown box in the view and type in the transfer amount. My question is, will doing something like this work with my specific model setup below where both account totals are in the same class? Or would it be best to give each student an ICollection of accounts?

Also is it correct practice to handle the logic of the transfer in and action result like this? Or is it best to handle that in a model?

**Psuedo code for what I am trying to do**

```
    public ActionResult TransferFunds(int firstAccountId, Int SecondAccountID, decimal transferAmount)
{
    var account1 = //find first account from context
    var account2 = //find second account from context

    if(account1 amount >= transferAmount)
    {
        account1 amount -= transferAmount;
        account2 amount += transferAmount;
    }
    save changes
}
```

Thank you for you time to look at this and for your help.

Here are the relevant models that I referred to.

**Models For User, Student, and Account**

```
    public class User
{
    [Key]
    [Editable(false)]
    [ForeignKey("UserProfile")]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name is required.")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last name is required.")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**Student**

```
    public class Student : User
{
    [ForeignKey("Account")]
    [Editable(false)]
    public virtual int AccountID { get; set; }

    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }

    [Column("ClassroomID")]
    [ForeignKey("Classroom")]
    public virtual int ClassroomID { get; set; }

    public virtual Classroom Classroom { get; set; }
}
```

**Bank Account**

```
    public class Account
{
    [Key]
    [Editable(false)]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public virtual int AccountID { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
    [Column(TypeName = "money")]
    public virtual decimal CheckingsTotal { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
    [Column(TypeName = "money")]
    public virtual decimal SavingsTotal { get; set; }

    public decimal AccountTotal()
    {
        return SavingsTotal + CheckingsTotal;
    }
```

Comment: Deleting and reposting is not going to help you. I ask again: what *specific problems* have you encountered while making an effort to do this?

Comment: I apologize, but I am absolutely lost on trying to do this. I am not looking for someone to write this for me, just to point me in the right direction.

Comment: In the right direction of what? You just want an outline of what to do? We can't do that.

Comment: I guess a more specific question would be: Does my current "Account" model work for making a transfer, or to be able to add and subtract an amount from the same class will I need to give the student a collection of accounts that each have their own name and total?

Comment: Can you create pseudo code that shows us exactly what it is that you want to do?

Comment: And once I have the account set up correctly, how would the transfer be done? Should I have another method inside my model class that would take the different accounts as parameters than a decimal for the transfer amount, or would that be bad practice since the model would be talking directly to the view?

Comment: Just added in the pseudo code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like your question is not really about MVC or EF, but is rather about class design and domain modelling - which is a very broad subject so will be hard for anyone to give you a good answer.  It will be worth your time doing some reading on the subject.

However, here a few pointers:

The rough design you have given above may "work" - but there are several issues with it.

For instance, if you decide users need more than just a "checking" and "savings" account, you will need to modify the `Account` class and the underlying database.  It would be better for user to have an ICollection of Accounts, as you suggest.

Generally speaking, it is a bad idea to have that sort of logic in your controller.  Controller actions should not have much logic in them.  This kind of logic is fundamental to your Model, and so this is where it should sit.  It would be too easy for a small mistake in a controller to mean that you put money in one account, without taking money out of another.

Consider also that transferring money from one account to another is not quite as simple subtracting from one account and adding to another - what if the first account doesn't have enough money in it?  What if the second account isn't owned by the same user as the first account?  What if later on you decide there are accounts you can make deposit in, but not a withdrawl from?  etc etc

The logic around transferring money could become quite complex, and you don't want littered throughout your controllers - it is best to have all this in one place, your Model.

You could consider a `AccountManager` that is in charge of doing this sort of thing

e.g.

```
public class AccountManager
{

    public void TransferMoney(Account srcAccount, Account destAccount, Decimal amount) 
    {
       //...transfer money...
    }

}
```

and have your controller call this method to arrange the transfer.

It is best that you do some reading, come up with a design, and try it out.  If there is something specific about the design you have come up with that you don't like or aren't sure about, post a specific question on StackOverflow, and I'm sure someone will be able to help.  Broad general questions are less likely to get very helpful repsonses.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very helpful! I will definitely do some research on both class design and domain modeling within MVC and applications in general. Thanks again.